# BPA in reciepts (cashier)

Tags: chemical

I'm a cashier and handle heaps of receipts every weekday.

I found this study: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4927604/, demonstrating significantly higher levels of urinary free and bound BPA in cashiers than non-cashiers.

However, I lack the relevant technical expertise to determine if such levels present in cashiers are a cause for concern.

> Free and total BPA were detected in all samples. The median urinary total BPA concentration was 3.54 µg/L (2.89 µg/g creatinine) for controls and 8.92 µg/L (6.76 µg/g creatinine) for cashiers. For the free BPA, the median urinary concentration was 0.20 µg/L (0.21 µg/g creatinine) for controls and 0.28 µg/L (0.22 µg/g creatinine) for cashiers.

The study noted that these findings were 'interesting' for risk assessment but made no prescriptive comment (unfortunately).

Please tell me if this is to worry about.

Comment: That's an interesting finding I was unaware of, making your question an interesting one. However, asking if you should worry about it is overly broad. The better question would be what effects do those levels of BPA have, so I've edited your question accordingly. If you disagree, you can revert my edits.

Comment: @CareyGregory changing the question after I've answered it?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Sorry, you're right. I reverted my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no one knows.

> By now tests have found the chemical in more than 90% of Americans. But the risks of BPA contamination are still in dispute. One reason: Studies have produced conflicting or inconclusive results, in part because alterations in the endocrine system can be subtle and hard to pin down. Another is a deep rift between academic scientists and regulators about which kinds of studies are best for shaping government oversight of chemicals. <sup>1</sup>

The increased exposure as a teller is likely from handling thermal receipt paper, and there's a suggestion that sweating might increase clearance from the body. <sup>2</sup>

http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/02/bpa-safety-war-battle-over-evidence

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jeph/2012/185731/